# Cache value until task goes to sleep

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Is it possible to "cache" a value until a task is put to sleep with `await`? Once the task is awake again, the value is re-calculated.

Example:

```rust
tokio::task::spawn(async {
  loop {
    let now = cached(|| { chrono::offset::Utc::now().naive_utc() });
    println!("Now: {:?}", now);

    let now = cached(|| { chrono::offset::Utc::now().naive_utc() });
    // `now` is the same as before
    
    some_async_task().await;

    let now = cached(|| { chrono::offset::Utc::now().naive_utc() });
    // `now` is different because the task went to sleep and woke up
  }
})
```

A use case could be fetching the current time, which is going to be very similar if fetched multiple times during the awake period, but is relatively expensive to calculate, so the benefit of having a fresh value is low.

Comment: I assume you mean something more convenient/automatic than just re-assigning to the variable, yes?

Comment: Yes, because it'll be tough to get the variable if we are a few functions deep inside the call stack. This simple example doesn't show that nuance.

Comment: So you want it to be global?

Comment: "Global" to the task I think would be ideal. Global to the executable could be interesting as well, but will require atomics/locking.